# geometry view for projector calibration

Tags: image, geometry, project

I’m not that good in geometry. I need to calibrate a projector to project on the ground. To do this process I need to use a frontal chart, as shown in this picture [image].
I know already the height of projector from the ground, and the distances of projected points (A,B,C and D) from the projector. I need to know the coordinates of points projected on the chart, perpendicular with the ground level. 
Do triangle rule work for this problematic? Or are there some other techniques in the transformation world?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, triangle rule works here for vertical coordinates of a,b,c,d points. For example,

```
c.y / h = D2 / (D1+D2)
```

But you have not enough information to get horizontal positions for these points.

Comment: thanks, Do you think if I consider the origin at the projector, I can find the horizontal measures on the axis X on coordnate system (x,y,z) ?

Comment: I mean Y axis is vertical (c-b) and c-d direction as horizontal. It is worth to define - how x,y,z axes are related to your picture.

Comment: I added my x,y,z directions